# Get data inside object in firebase firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have following Structure in my firebase `firestore`

[image]

I want to get data of Form1 and Form2 how to achieve..

Below is what i tried

```
 registration=  query.whereEqualTo("UID", sharedPref.getString("userId",null)).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (e != null) {

                }
                for (DocumentChange documentChange : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {


                    if (documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("mobileMenus") != null) {

                        try {
                            Log.d("order","one");
                            String notesResponse = documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("mobileMenus").toString().replace(" ", "").replace(":", "");
                            String responseNotes = notesResponse.replace("=", ":");

                            Log.d("shownotes","*****    "+responseNotes);

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseNotes);

                            isAttendance = jsonObject.getString("Attendance");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("isAttendance",isAttendance);

                            isCalender = jsonObject.getString("Calender");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("Calender",isCalender);

                            isExpenses = jsonObject.getString("Expenses");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("Expenses",isExpenses);

                            isleaves = jsonObject.getString("Leaves");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("Leaves",isleaves);

                            isLogout = jsonObject.getString("LogOut");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("LogOut",isLogout);

                            isNoticeboard = jsonObject.getString("NoticeBoard");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("NoticeBoard",isNoticeboard);

                            isTasks = jsonObject.getString("Tasks");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("Tasks",isTasks);

                            isTrackEmployee = jsonObject.getString("TrackEmployee");
                            shared_menueditor.putString("TrackEmployee",isTrackEmployee);

                           // documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("dynForms");
                           // Log.d("total", String.valueOf(documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("dynForms")));
                            Log.d("order","two");
                            forms= (Map<String, Object>) documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("mobileMenus");

                            Log.d("showfomsizes","***   "+forms.size());



                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                    if (forms!= null) {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> form : forms.entrySet()) {
                            String key = form.getKey();
                            Map<Object, Object> values = (Map<Object, Object>) form.getValue();
                            name = (String) values.get("name");
                            String id = (String) values.get("id");
                            Log.d("nesteddata", name + "......" + id + "......." + key);
                            if (key.contains("Form1")) {
                                shared_menueditor.putString("nav_form1",name);
                            }
                            if (key.contains("Form2")) {
                                shared_menueditor.putString("nav_form2",name);
                            }
                            if (key.contains("Form3")) {
                                shared_menueditor.putString("nav_form3",name);
                            }
                        }
                        shared_menueditor.apply();
                        shared_menueditor.commit();

                    }
                    userprofile();

                }



            }

        });
```

> I am able to get Attendance,Calender,etc..But my pbm is i am not able
>   to get **Form1** and **Form2** datas

**Error:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.Map**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that exception because you are not checking for the Boolean values that you have. This should be your code snippet for getting the `forms`. Your `forms` object is the entire `mobileMenus` object.

```
if (forms!= null) {
   for (Map.Entry<String, Object> form : forms.entrySet()) {
       String key = form.getKey();
       if(key.contains("Form")) {
           Map<Object, Object> values = (Map<Object, Object>) form.getValue();
           name = (String) values.get("name");
           String id = (String) values.get("id");
           Log.d("nesteddata", name + "......" + id + "......." + key);
           if (key.contains("Form1")) {                               
               shared_menueditor.putString("nav_form1",name);
           }
           if (key.contains("Form2")) {                  
               shared_menueditor.putString("nav_form2",name);
           }
           if (key.contains("Form3")) {                             
               shared_menueditor.putString("nav_form3",name);
           }
         }
       }

   }
```